# Как дублировать сайт?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Есть сайт на домене 1.ru с двумя html страницами и кучей файлов, картинок и тп.

Нужно подключить к нему второй домен 2.ru, но чтобы все файлы лежали на первом, а второй был пустой.

Как проще это сделать? Может на втором что-то прописать в .htaccess или в php? Только не редирект, адрес должен работать 2.ru

Comment: доменную запись на тот же ip и все, иными словами назначьте сайту два доменных имени

Comment: Доменная запись и так на том же ip, они на одном сервере. Или не так понял?

Comment: в чем вопрос тогда? если по обоим адрес открывается одно и то же, что вы еще хотите?

Comment: Где меняется запись? На сервере или у регистратора?

Comment: регистратор должен направить нс на ваш сервер. ваш сервер в свою очередь должен сопоставить сайт с адресом.

Comment: У регистратора и так одинаковые ip. Один по своему пути файлов работает, на своём